# Javascript objects keep getting converted to array in laravel backend

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I started experiencing something strange in my laravel.vuejs application today. When i pass a JS object from vuejs frontend to laravel backend, it gets converted to array. For example, in vuejs

```
data() {
    return {
        user: {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            age: ''
        },
    }
 },
methods: {
        submit(){
           axios.post(this.api + '/test', {
                user: this.user
            }).then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })
        }
    },
```

In my laravel controller, `print_r($request->user)` shows the object as an array.

```
Array
(
    [name] => 
    [email] => 
    [age] => 
)
```

How do i fix this? I am using laravel5.8
NB: I noticed this started happening after i ran composer update. Could this be the cause?

NB: After creating the model, I get back a response of array instead of JSON, even after returning the response as JSON. That is the problem.

Comment: there is no "object" in http protocol. What is the issue of it being an array ? why dont you convert it to object `(object)$request->user`

Comment: @Flexi, Laravel always did convert JSON to Array if possible... This is not new

Answer (score 2):

Object concept doesn't exist in HTTP protocol and you can't send your data with requests as an object. you can get the input as json object and decode it, but that will be a [StdClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) object. So, you can assign the request array to the user model and use it as an object.

Example:
Suppose you created a `User` model and you want to assign the array as an attribute.

```
$user = new User($request->user);

// or 

$user = new User();
$user->fill($request->user);

// or

$user = new User();
$user->name = $request->user['name']
$user->age = $request->user['age']
...
```

**Note**: It's better to validate the inputs before assign to the user object. you can do it clearly with [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: The problem is that after creating the model, I get a response of array instead of an array, even after casting response as JSON.